# How to integrate in Swift using vDSP

Tags: ios, swift, accelerate-framework

I try to find replacement for [SciPy's `cumtrapz` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.4.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html) function in Swift. I found something called [`vDSP_vtrapzD`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450810-vdsp_vtrapzd#) but I have no idea how to use it. This is what I've done so far:

```
import Accelerate
var f1: [Double] = [<some data>]
var tdata: [Double] = [<time vector>]
var output = [Double](unsafeUninitializedCapacity:Int(f1.count), initializingWith: {_, _ in})

vDSP_vtrapzD(&f1, 1, &tdata, &output, 1, vDSP_Length(f1.count))
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I'll add: If you name your variables something more useful than `f1` and `tdata`, you won't need to write comments like `some data` and `time vector`. You could have just named your variables that :p

Comment: I'm sorry. It has more sense in my calculations and I forgot to change it when I posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but you're using `Array.init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)` incorrectly. From [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3200717-init):

> ##### Discussion
>
> Inside the closure, set the `initializedCount` parameter to the number of elements that are initialized by the closure. The memory in the range `buffer[0..<initializedCount]` must be initialized at the end of the closure’s execution, and the memory in the range `buffer[initializedCount...]` must be uninitialized. This postcondition must hold even if the `initializer` closure throws an error.

This API is a more unsafe (but performant counterpart) to [`Array.init(repeating:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init#), which allocates an array of a fixed size, and spends the time to initialize all its contents). This has two potential drawbacks:

- If the purpose of the array is to provide a buffer to write a result into, then initializing it prior to that is redundant and wasteful
- If the result you put into that buffer ends up being larger than your
  array, you need to remember to manually "trim" the excess off by
  copying it into a new array.

`Array.init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)` improves upon this by:

- Asking you for the maximum capacity you might possibly need
- Giving you a temporary buffer with the capacity

  - Importantly, it's uninitialized. This makes it faster, but also more dangerous (risk of [buffer underflow errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002577-SW1)) if used incorrectly.
  - You then tell it exactly how much of that temporary buffer you *actually* used
  - It will automatically copy that much of the buffer into the final array, and return that as the result.

You're using `Array.init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity:initializingWith:)` as if it were [`Array.init(repeating:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init#). To use it correctly, you would put your initialization logic inside the `initializer` parameter, like so:

```
let result = Array<Double>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: f1.count, initializingWith: { resultBuffer, count in
    assert(f1.count == tdata.count)
    
    vDSP_vtrapzD(
        &f1,                       // Double-precision real input vector.
        1,                         // Address stride for A.
        &tdata,                    // Pointer to double-precision real input scalar: step size.
        resultBuffer.baseAddress!, // Double-precision real output vector.
        1,                         // Address stride for C.
        vDSP_Length(f1.count)      // The number of elements to process.,
    )
    
    count = f1.count // This tells Swift how many elements of the buffer to copy into the resultant Array
})
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there's a nice Swift version of `vDSP_vtrapzD` that you can see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/integration_functions. The variant that returns the result uses the `unsafeUninitializedCapacity` initializer.

On a related note, there's also a nice Swift API to Quadrature: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/quadrature-smu

simon

Answer (score 0):

I've been grappling with using DSP in the last week too! Alexander's solution above was helpful. However I'd like to add a couple of things.

vDSP_vtrapzD only allows you to integrate an array of values against a fixed step increment, which is a scalar value. The function doesn't allow you to pass a varying time value for each increment.

The example solution confused me a little as it does a check to make sure the time array is the same size as the data array. This is not necessary as only the first value in the time vector will be used by the vDSP_vtrapzD function.

It's a shame that the vDSP_vtrapzD only takes a scalar as ca a fixed time component. In my experience this doesn't not reflect reality when working with time based data from sensors that don't emit data in precisely the same increments.